# Error Times Roman is not embedded in the paper

Tags: ieeetran

I have to submit my paper today in few hours but I'm getting the error that Times Roman is not embedded in the paper, however, I'm using the IEEE template and I'm using tikzpicture to draw my blocks, I tried to look for solutions but none worked with me. I hope you can help with that.

```
    \documentclass[conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,snakes}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\tikzset{options/.code={\tikzset{#1}}} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,shadows.blur,shadings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\input{\Conf/glossary}
\makeglossaries

\graphicspath{{\Conf /Figures/}}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: no it doesn't help since we don't have a pdf printer in Mac anymore

Comment: The linked thread discusses multiple options, I think.